# Angular 2 - When to use the inject function and when to not use it

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I have a question in creating specs/unit tests in Angular2. Whenever you are injecting a mocked service, when do you use the ***inject function*** as the one below

```
it('function that the component calls',
  inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => { // ...
}));
```

Or when do you use it as the one below

```
beforeEach(() => {
  let myMockService = new MyMockService();

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      { provide: MyService, useValue: myMockService }
    ]
  });
  TestBed.overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
    set: {
      providers: [
        { provide: MyService, useValue: myMockService }
      ]
    }
  });
})
```

Can someone enlighten me on the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason to use it is to **get access to the service in your test**, when *Angular is creating it*. For instance

```
providers: [ MyService ]
```

Here Angular is creating it, and you only have access to it through Angular's injector.

But you're providing the service as a *value* then there is no need to use `inject` as you already have access to it

```
let serviceInstance = new Service();

provider: [ { provide: MyService, useValue: serviceInstance } ]
```

Here you already have access to `serviceInstance` so no need to get it from the injector.

Also if you don't need to access to the service inside the test, then there's not even a need to try and access it. But sometimes your mock will have thing you want to do with it inside the test.

Aside from `inject`, there are only ways to access the service

#### *You could...*

For your particular example you don't need `inject` at all. You just need to move the mock outside the scope of the `beforeEach` so that the `it` can use it

```
let myMockService = new MyMockService();

beforeEach(() => {

})

it('function that the component calls', () => {
  myMockService.doSomething();
}));
```

#### *You could...*

Instead of using `inject`, you could get it from the `TestBed`, which acts like an injector. Maybe this is preferred as you can add it in your `beforeEach`

```
let service;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [ MyService ]
  });

  service = TestBed.get(MyService);
})

it('function that the component calls', () => {
  service.doSomething();
}));
```

#### *You could...*

Get it from the `DebugElement` which also acts like an injector

```
it('function that the component calls', () => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  let service = fixture.debugElement.get(MyService);
}));
```

So it's really a matter of preference. I personally try to stop using `inject`, as there are the other, less verbose options.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @peeskillet

Answer (score 0):

You use `inject()` when you want to get instances from the provide passed into your test code (for example the HTTP `MockBackend`) or any other service you want to communicate to directly in your test code.

`TestBed.configureXxx` only sets up providers for the test component.

Comment: So does this mean that the service that is injected to my **MyComponent** does not need to be passed in the _inject function_? If my **MyComponent**'s constructor is **constructor(public service:MyService)**

Comment: No, `inject()` is only necessary if you want a reference in your test code.